# jQuery show and hide dependent on value in C.I drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Working in a single view, I have the following C.I form_dropdown:

```
<?php
$international_options = array(
    '0' => lang('No'),
    '1' => lang('Yes')
);
echo form_dropdown('International', $international_options, set_value('International', isset($stockists->International) ? $stockists->International : 0), 'class="span4 selectpicker international"');
?>
```

And I have the following file up-loader:

```
<label class="flagupload" for="filename">Upload an image flag</label>
<input class='flagupload' type='file' name='filename' size='20' />
```

On the same view (at the bottom of the view), I have the following script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#select.international").change(function() {
            if ($('#select option:selected').text() == "yes") {
                $('.flagupload').show();
            }
            else if ($('#select option:selected').text() == "no") {
                $('.flagupload').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This attempts to hide instances of `flagupload` if the drop-down is set to no, or it hides the class if the dropdown is set to 'yes'.

This currently does not work, but doesn't error either. Can anyone spot the issue?

The HTML markup for the dropdown is as follows:

```
<select name="International" class="span4 selectpicker international">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please provide your drop down code.

Comment: @AliKhanusiya see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below short code.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("select.international").change(function() {
           $('.flagupload').addClass('hide'); 
           if ($(this).val() == "1") {
               $('.flagupload').removeClass('hide');
           }
       });
   });
</script>
<style>
   .hide
   {
        display:none ;
   }
</style>
<select name="International" class="span4 selectpicker international">
   <option value="0">No</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Yes</option>
</select>
<label class="flagupload hide" for="filename">Upload an image flag</label>
<input class="flagupload hide" type='file' name='filename' size='20' />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select.international").change(function() {
            if ($('select option:selected').text() == "yes") {
                $('.flagupload').show();
            }
            else if ($('select option:selected').text() == "no") {
                $('.flagupload').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think it should be like above.

Change #select to select.

Comment: No joy with that sorry.